php artisan test on laravel 8 raises ERROR: Command "test" is not defined. Did you mean one of these?
Laravel version: 8
php version: 8.1
When I run php artisan test, I get Command "tests" is not defined.
I added nunomaduro/collision to my dependencies, and I get the error:
NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\Exceptions\RequirementsException 

  Running Collision ^5.0 artisan test command requires at least PHPUnit ^9.0.

If you dig down into the dependencies, you find that php 8.1 requires PhpUnit ^10, but nunomaduro/collision requires PhpUnit ^9.
I know the issue resides with running laravel 8 on php 8.1 instead of 7.4, but the application is in production and I would like to run php artisan test without changing the laravel version.
Tried and did not work:

Forcing nunomaduro/collision to the next version 6.0 -> fails to install due to laravel framework dependencies

Commenting out the code for the version lock -> error : option unknown --printer


Any ideas?
